# How do i Meteor Reset client subscription

Tags: javascript, meteor

i have subscribe and publish like this :

publish.js :

```
Meteor.publish('ProductWithSkipAndLimit', function(skip,limit){
return Product.find({}, {
        sort: {
            createdAt: 1
        },
        skip: skip,
        limit: limit
    });
});
```

subscribe.js :

```
Meteor.subscribe('ProductWithSkipAndLimit',0,10);
```

and it will return to client 10 products from 0 sort by createdAt.
Nah i have an event click like this :

```
'click' : function(e){
e.preventDefault();
Meteor.subscribe('ProductWithSkipAndLimit',10,10);
}
```

I want to get 10 more products. okay i get that products, but 10 products not reset. so on client i have 20 products.

how i can reset client subscription? so client only have 10 products every subscribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor.subscribe:

> Subscribe to a record set. Returns a handle that provides stop() and ready() methods.

You need to take handle of Meteor.subscribe

```
subscription = Meteor.subscribe('ProductWithSkipAndLimit',10,10);
```

And in events object :

```
var subscription;

Template.NAME.events({
    'click' : function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      subscription && subscription.stop();
      subscription = Meteor.subscribe('ProductWithSkipAndLimit',10,10);
    }
})
```

Comment: Hello kuba but i place subscription on ironrouter waiton

Comment: So i believe the way to go is to pass subscription from IronRouter waiton to be accessible inside Template through Session. Then on first click on pagination start using subscrition from Template.events, like described above. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score -1):

I think, in `click` event you have to set Session variable `Session.set('more', true);`

On client:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
   if(Session.get('more')) {
     Meteor.subscribe('ProductWithSkipAndLimit',10,10);
     Session.set('more', false);
   }
});
```

Or some logic to set current position in collection (10, 20, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

You asked about subscription resetting, but it looks like there is no need to do it manually in your case.

You can subscribe within `Tracker.autorun` and pass reactive values as subscription parameters.

Then on each `skip`/`limit` session variable change the subscription will be reset automatically.

From [Meteor official documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe):

> If you call Meteor.subscribe within a reactive computation, for example using Tracker.autorun, the subscription will automatically be cancelled when the computation is invalidated or stopped; it's not necessary to call stop on subscriptions made from inside autorun.

Here is working example (METEOR@1.1.0.2):

```
Items = new Meteor.Collection("items");

if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Tracker.autorun(function() {
        Meteor.subscribe("items", Session.get("skip"), Session.get("limit"));
    });

    Template.main.helpers({
        items: function() {
            return Items.find({});
        }
    });

    Template.main.events({
        'click #next' : function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var skip = Session.get("skip");
            Session.set("skip", skip + Session.get("limit"));
        },   
        'click #prev' : function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var skip = Session.get("skip");
            Session.set("skip", skip - Session.get("limit"));
        }
    });

    Meteor.startup(function() {
        Session.set("skip", 0);
        Session.set("limit", 10);
    });
}

if(Meteor.isServer) {
    if (Items.find({}).fetch().length < 100) {
        _.times(100, function(n) {
            Items.insert({
                name: String(n),
                createdAt: new Date()
            });
        });
    }

    Meteor.publish("items", function(skip, limit) {        
        return Items.find({}, { limit: limit, skip: skip, sort: { createdAt: 1} });
    });
}
```

template

```
<template name="main">
    <header>
        <h1>Items</h1>
        <nav>
            <button id="prev">prev</button>
            <button id="next">next</button>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <ul>
    {{#each items}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

P.S. Don't forget to remove "autopublish" package

Comment: It would be nice to know why an answer is downvoted.